# I don't know how to get my correct output (Beginner programmer)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm unsure what to put in the blank line. This is what my input looks like (I don't know what to put after "for item in food:" :

```
food = ["Pasta","Cakes","Oranges"]

for item in food:
      __________________
```

I need the output to look like:

```
I like Pasta 
I like Cakes 
I like Oranges
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you are using python 3:

```
for item in food:
    print('I like {}'.format(item))
```

If you are using 2, just remove the parentheses.